# I won't be misunderstood

Tags: grammar

Let's say you making a clarification statement with a colleague...

> ''I'd like to clarify this ___etc____ so I won't be misunderstood.''

Is this grammatical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'd like to clarify this so I won't be misunderstood. (**explanation**)"

"So I won't be misunderstood, I'd like to clarify ...etc..."

Putting the purpose of clarification first is the common way.

Comment: But is it grammatically correct? That's my question. thx for the tip by the way.

Comment: The way it is in your question right now it is but if the "etc" is a long story then no. I'm not exactly sure what the "etc" is supposed to represent. Like if you were saying "I'd like to clarify this conversation so I won't be missunderstood." That is correct.

Comment: How about 'I'd like to clarify this comparison between tablets and cellphones so I won't be misundertood.''

Comment: @JohnArvin yes totally fine and correct